# Cast exception in child class

Tags: c#, oop

I have two classes ClassA and CLassB. ClassA is an abstract class. ClassB derives from ClassA. I have one DTO named ParentDTO.

```
public class ParentDTO
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ClassA
{
    public abstract void CreateUser(ParentDTO dto);
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public override void CreateUser(ParentDTO dto)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You are in class ClassB");
    }
}
```

Now I have one DTO(MyDTO), which derives from ParentDTO.

```
public class MyDTO: ParentDTO
{
    public int MyID { get; set; }
}
```

I have extended ClassB further:

```
public class ClassC : ClassB
{
    public override void CreateUser(ParentDTO dto)
    {
        var mydto = (MyDTO) dto;// This throws cast exception
        mydto.MyID=222;
    }
}
```

I am using the above code as :

```
    ClassC c = new ClassC();
    ParentDTO dto=new ParentDTO();
    c.CreateUser(dto);
```

Can someone please tell me how to cast DTO above in CreateUser method of ClassC. I want to use mydto.MyID in my code. I know I am doing something like casting Animal to Lion instead of Lion to Animal. But is there any way to use child DTO ID? Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your object is a `ParentDTO` which doesn't have a MyID field. Its not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers are correct, but the reason for this behavior would be clearer with a better understanding of the difference between "static type" and "run-time type", which they do not discuss.  Static type is the type of a variable in your C# code, while run-time type is the type of an actual object in memory.

We all know that static type and run-time type may differ.  Consider:

```
class A { }
class B : A { }

A a = new B();
```

The variable `a` refers to an instance of type `B`.  The static type of the variable is `A`, but the run-time type of the object is `B`.

We can also think of `a` as holding a *reference of type A* that refers to *an instance of type B*.  This is allowed if and only if type B is derived from (or equal to) type A.

The following, therefore, is not allowed:

```
B b = new A();
```

Here, you are attempting to assign a reference to an instance of type A (run-time type) to a variable of (static) type B.  A is not derived from or equal to B, so the assignment is not allowed.  Similarly, the following assignments are not allowed:

```
string s = new object();
MyDTO dto = new ParentDTO();
```

The cast operator complicates things somewhat, but the underlying issue is the same: *you are attempting to set a reference to point to an object whose run-time type is not derived from or equal to the static type of the reference:*

```
A a1 = new A();
B b1 = new B();

A a2 = (A)b1;  // fine, because B is derived from A
B b2 = (B)a1;  // not allowed, because A is not derived from B.
```

Again, this might make more sense if we substitute `object` for `A` and `string` for `B`:

```
object a1 = new object();
string b1 = "Hello, World!";

object a2 = (object)b1;  // a2 now points to the string "Hello, World!";
string b2 = (string)a1;  // cast fails: the string variable can't point to an instance of `object`
```

Similarly, with your types:

```
ParentDTO a1 = new ParentDTO();
MyDTO     b1 = new MyDTO();

ParentDTO a2 = (ParentDTO)b1;  // works
MyDTO     b2 = (MyDTO)a1;;     // doesn't
```

Answer (score 1):

you are just using the interface architecture in wrong way. Add get, set to ParentDTO class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast a parent type variable to a child type unless it was initialized as the child type (or another type derived from the child type).

```
ClassC c = new ClassC();
ParentDTO dto = new MyDTO();
c.CreateUser(dto);
```

Comment: Unless it was initialized as the child type *or another type derived from the child type*.

Answer (score 0):

You created an instance of class `ParentDTO`. Casting it to `MyDTO` correctly yields this exception as the instance is really of type `ParentDTO` and not of type `MyDTO`.
The object instance you have there doesn't have a property with name `MyID`, it simply doesn't exist, so there is no way to get that - non-existing - value.

Maybe you should describe what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

> *Can someone please tell me how to cast DTO above in CreateUser method of ClassC*

No way. You created object of base type using base type in declaration. You cannot just cast it to derived type, it's illegal.
Use

`ParentDTO dto=new MyDto();`

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)